# How to replace current value to defined string

Tags: sql

the query result

```
select ( LENGTH(testid) - LENGTH(replace(testid, '/', '')) ) as num_slashes,
 count(*) from test.1 where isdeleted = false  group by ( LENGTH(testid) - LENGTH(replace(testid, '/', '')) )
 ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

from database returned :

[image]

i would like to replaced the 0, 1, 2
to master1, master2, master3.

what query should I used so the query result will be

[image]

Comment: Hint:  Use a `case` expression.

Comment: How do the numbers `0`, `1` and `2` map to the strings master1, master2, master3? Are they arbitrary or related to records in `test.1` or some other table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
select (case ( LENGTH(testid) - LENGTH(replace(testid, '/', '')) ) 
            when 1 then 'master1'
            when 2 then 'master2' 
            when 3 then 'master3'
        end) as num_slashes,
       count(*)
from test.1
where isdeleted = false
group by ( LENGTH(testid) - LENGTH(replace(testid, '/', '')) )
order by COUNT(*)
```

Comment: select (case ( LENGTH(testid) - LENGTH(replace(testid, '/', '')) ) 
            when 0 then 'master1'
            when 1 then 'master2' 
            when 2 then 'master3'
        end) as num_slashes,
       count(*)
from test.1
where isdeleted = false
group by ( LENGTH(testid) - LENGTH(replace(testid, '/', '')) )
order by COUNT(*)

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify your query by using a derived table to compute `num_slashes` and then using a `CASE` expression to convert that value into a string:

```
SELECT CASE num_slashes WHEN 0 THEN 'master1'
                        WHEN 1 THEN 'master2'
                        ELSE 'master3'
       END AS number_slashes,
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
  SELECT ( LENGTH(testid) - LENGTH(replace(testid, '/', '')) ) AS num_slashes
  FROM test.1
  WHERE isdeleted = false
) t
GROUP BY num_slashes
ORDER BY num_slashes
```